# need to add commas between double quotes php output

Tags: php, android, replaceall

I use the output of PHP in an android application, the php code generates output like:

```
"x""y""z"
```

I want to separate between them using commas whether by changing the php code or using programming in android.
to be

```
"x","y","z"
```

I tried by programming using ReplaceAll to replace every ("") by (",") but I can't put this in the syntax of command as it refuses to do """", "",""

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ESM");
$coresite = $_POST["selectedcoresite"];
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Cabinet_Row FROM cabinets WHERE Core_Site=?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("s", $coresite);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Cabinet_Row);
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
echo json_encode($Cabinet_Row);
}
$stmt->close();
}
else{
$mysqli->close();    
}
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want a comma? so just add one to the string output:

```
echo json_encode($Cabinet_Row).','; //leaves a final comma
```

you could concatenate the results and echo once:

```
$out=array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
$out[]=$Cabinet_Row);
}
$stmt->close();
}

echo '"'.implode('","',$out).'"';
```

i see no real need for `json_encode()` considering your output.

Comment: yeah this works :) .. it looks simple I know but I am so new to programming (two weeks) .. so I searched and I failed to find how to add , over echo json_encode. if you have any link shows how to control the output of php file I would be grateful as I will use so many of them during my program. thanks

Comment: looking at your history you need to learn how to accept answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I thought I haven't enough reputation to accept it, I got it.